# Jest 28: createJestExpect - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')

Tags: jestjs

I migrated from Jest 27 to 28. If I try to start a test now, I just get this error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')

      at createJestExpect (node_modules/@jest/expect/build/index.js:35:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@jest/expect/build/index.js:47:20)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:317:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:407:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:338:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:190:3)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

I can't even debug my tests, because the internal test setup is already failing. Any clue, what's going wrong?

Comment: Bug still exists in Jest 29.

Answer (score 48):

This is a bug (see [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12889)) that appears when the `moduleDirectories` option includes `"."`.

To fix this, change `"."` to `"<rootDir>"`:

```json
moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>"]
```

Alternatively, if you use a  `jest.config.js` file, you can change `"."` to `__dirname`:

```js
module.exports = {
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", __dirname]
};
```

Comment: From that bug issue: "I fixed this issue by changing "moduleDirectories": [ "node_modules", "." ] to "moduleDirectories": [ "node_modules", "<rootDir>" ]"

Comment: Can confirm that this also fixed Jest 29.

Comment: @Paul I still had to apply it for Jest 29.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similiar error using angular together with jest. after updating jest and angular dependencies to the latest version i fixed this error in a slightly different way than @Lupina but using `<rootDir>` instead of `__dirname`. this is my current jest.config.js

```
jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@angular|rxjs)'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage/',
};
```